# How to change the pitch of sound in IOs?

Tags: ios, audio, cocos2d-iphone, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I am using Dirac.h in my project but its not working for arm64.
Its work fine for all other devices but not for the devices having architecture 64.
Kindly suggest me some better solution

Comment: Throwing the device will change the pitch of sound, if the device is moving relative to the observer.  ;-)

Comment: Does dirac.h come with Cocos2D or are you using FFMPEG or something else?

Comment: its with Cocos2D , i have to remove arm64 for running the app, but itunes is not accepting my aap

Answer (score 0):

```
cc.SimpleAudioEngine:getInstance():playEffect(pszFilePath,bLoop,pitch,pan,gain)
```

do you mean this pitch? this function has a Parameter is named pitch,and it works